# How to resolve the Composer related error shown using the Drush DL command?

Tags: drush, composer

I am working on MAMP and I have already installed a Drupal 7 site in my local machine ( not using Drush or Composer ). Then I have installed Composer and Drush ( [Installing Drush on MAMP](https://www.bramvandenbulcke.be/en/article/installing-drush-mamp) ). Now my Drupal site is under `htdocs` folder and it's working. If I run "drush" from htdocs via the command line, then it's shown a bunch of help command list.

But if I am trying to install any module using `drush dl Module_Name` then it gives me an error like so:

> [error]  dl has been deprecated. Please build your site using Composer. Add new projects with composer require drupal/[project-name]. Use https://www.drupal.org/project/composer_generate to build a composer.json which represents the the enabled modules on your site.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is? Do I need to install a fresh Drupal 7 site via Composer?

Comment: What do you get for `drush version`? It needs to be 8, not 9 for Drupal 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using composer is rather for Drupal 8 than Drupal 7
You could remove your version:

```
composer global remove drush/drush
```

and install an older one

```
composer global require drush/drush:8.*
```